# Definir valor default en una columna tipo imagen en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, imagen

Soy nuevo en bases de datos y me pregunto cómo puedo establecer un valor por defecto en una columna de tipo `image`

Esta es mi tabla:

```
create table TB_Producto
(
    idProd int primary key identity,
    nomProd varchar(70) not null,
    precio money not null,
    descripcion varchar(max),
    foto image,
    idCategoria int references TB_Categoria not null,
    stock int default(0) not null
)
go
```

Y quiero hacer algo como esto:

```
    create table TB_Producto
    (
        idProd int primary key identity,
        nomProd varchar(70) not null,
        precio money not null,
        descripcion varchar(max),
        foto image default (imagen almacenada en mi PC) ,
        idCategoria int references TB_Categoria not null,
        stock int default(0) not null
    )

go
```

Esto es debido a que las imágenes de la columna no pueden tener `null` y necesito establecer un valor binario por defecto.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, estas en el sitio en español por favor traduce la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Para comenzar, no utilices el tipo de dato `image`. De acuerdo a la documentación [el tipo `image` es obsoleto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y va a desaparecer del SQL Server en versiones futuras.

La recomendación es utiliza el tipo de dato [`varbinary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que es el adecuado para almacenar datos binarios, tal como una imagen.

Puedes establecer el valor default utilizando notación hexadecimal, que es `0x` seguido de una cadena de números hexadecimales que representan los bytes de la imagen.

Por ejemplo, para que el default sea la secuencia de 3 bytes `[00][FF][AA]`, puedes crear la tabla así:

```
create table Prueba (
    numero int
  , foto varbinary(max) default 0x00FFAA
);
go

insert into prueba (numero) values (1);
go

select * from Prueba;
go
```

Esto retorna:

```
(1 row affected)
numero      foto
----------- ---------
1           0x00FFAA

(1 row affected)
```

Dado que es poco probable que quieras escribir unos cuantos Kilobites de información en formato hexadecimal, puedes leer el contenido del archivo de imagen en una variable local y valerte del SQL dinámico para *generar* la sentencia de creación de la tabla, que luego mandas a ejecutar directamente.

He realizado esta prueba que me funciona correctamente para poner mi propia fotografía, almacenada en `c:\test\tono.jpg` como default en una tabla:

```
declare @ImgDefault varbinary(max);
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

select @ImgDefault = BulkColumn
  from OpenRowSet(Bulk 'c:\test\tono.jpg', single_blob) as img;

print 'Tamaño del archivo = ' + cast(datalength(@ImgDefault) as varchar);

set @SQL = 'create table PruebaImgDefault
(
    idImg int primary key
  , foto varbinary(max) default '  + convert(nvarchar(max), @ImgDefault, 1) + '
);';

exec(@SQL);
go
```